# Pycharm cannot connect to vagrant

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, vagrant

I'm having a lot of problems with Pycharm and Vagrant.

I can run my virtual machine successfully with `vagrant up` and I can do `vagrant ssh` too. The problem comes when I run my machine from pycharm. I added vagrant to pycharm using a python
2.7 remote interpreter. The instance folder, the host url and the python executable are all set correctly. The error I'm getting is:

[image]

Everything worked fine until I updated to the latest version of MacOs Big Sur.

What information do you need to find the problem?

Full trace of the error checking the logs:

```
2021-04-16 14:08:22,596 [78482036]   INFO - xecution.runners.ExecutionUtil - Error running '****-docrouter':<br>Error occurred while executing "vagrant status" inside "/Users/*****/Repos/******-vagrant-devbox" folder:
 
com.intellij.execution.ExecutionException: Error occurred while executing "vagrant status" inside "/Users/****+/Repos/*****-vagrant-devbox" folder:

    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.RemoteSdkCredentialsProducerImpl.getRemoteSdkCredentials(RemoteSdkCredentialsProducerImpl.java:97)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.RemoteSdkCredentialsProducerImpl.getRemoteSdkCredentials(RemoteSdkCredentialsProducerImpl.java:85)
    at com.jetbrains.python.remote.PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.getRemoteSdkCredentials(PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.java:236)
    at com.jetbrains.python.remote.PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.getRemoteSdkCredentials(PyRemoteSdkAdditionalData.java:25)
    at com.jetbrains.python.remote.console.PythonConsoleSshProcessCreatorBase.createRemoteTunnel(pythonConsoleSshProcessCreators.kt:96)
    at com.jetbrains.python.scientific.figures.PySciEnvironmentProvider.createRemotePortForwarding(PySciEnvironmentProvider.java:154)
    at com.jetbrains.python.scientific.figures.PySciEnvironmentProvider.extendEnvironment(PySciEnvironmentProvider.java:119)
    at com.jetbrains.python.run.PythonCommandLineState.initEnvironment(PythonCommandLineState.java:578)
    at com.jetbrains.python.run.PythonCommandLineState.createPythonCommandLine(PythonCommandLineState.java:519)
    at com.jetbrains.python.run.PythonCommandLineState.generateCommandLine(PythonCommandLineState.java:478)
    at com.jetbrains.python.run.PythonCommandLineState.generateCommandLine(PythonCommandLineState.java:421)
    at com.jetbrains.python.run.PythonCommandLineState.startProcess(PythonCommandLineState.java:275)
    at com.jetbrains.django.run.DjangoServerRunCommandLineState.startProcess(DjangoServerRunCommandLineState.java:318)
    at com.jetbrains.python.run.PythonCommandLineState.execute(PythonCommandLineState.java:182)
    at com.jetbrains.python.run.PythonCommandLineState.execute(PythonCommandLineState.java:156)
    at com.jetbrains.python.run.PythonRunner.lambda$execute$1(PythonRunner.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while executing "vagrant status" inside "/Users/******/Repos/****-vagrant-devbox" folder:

    at com.jetbrains.plugins.vagrant.cli.VagrantCli.execVagrantStatusCommand(VagrantCli.java:298)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.vagrant.VagrantInstance.getCliVagrantStatus(VagrantInstance.java:172)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.vagrant.VagrantInstance.lambda$createVagrantMachinesResolver$9(VagrantInstance.java:377)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.vagrant.state.FileCache.getContent(FileCache.kt:21)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.vagrant.VagrantInstance.getUpdatedVagrantStatus(VagrantInstance.java:158)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.vagrant.VagrantInstance.getDefaultMachine(VagrantInstance.java:89)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.vagrant.VagrantInstance.getSshConfig(VagrantInstance.java:79)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.vagrant.VagrantUtil.getVagrantCredentials(VagrantUtil.java:44)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.vagrant.VagrantSupportImpl.getCredentials(VagrantSupportImpl.java:40)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.VagrantCredentialsUtil.getVagrantRemoteCredentials(VagrantCredentialsUtil.java:46)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.VagrantCredentialsUtil.getAndCheckVagrantRemoteCredentials(VagrantCredentialsUtil.java:22)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.RemoteSdkCredentialsProducerImpl.lambda$produceRemoteSdkCredentials$1(RemoteSdkCredentialsProducerImpl.java:52)
    at com.intellij.remote.ext.CredentialsCase$1.process(CredentialsCase.java:38)
    at com.intellij.remote.RemoteConnectionCredentialsWrapper.switchType(RemoteConnectionCredentialsWrapper.java:78)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.RemoteSdkCredentialsProducerImpl.produceRemoteSdkCredentials(RemoteSdkCredentialsProducerImpl.java:46)
    at com.jetbrains.plugins.remotesdk.RemoteSdkCredentialsProducerImpl.getRemoteSdkCredentials(RemoteSdkCredentialsProducerImpl.java:94)
    ... 22 more
```

### UPDATE

My coworker is facing the same problem, but he has vagrant `2.2.13` and the error message has changed to

[image]

I have Vagrant 2.2.14 but that does not solve the problem.

- Vagrant version: Vagrant 2.2.14
- Pycharm 2021.1

Comment: Not an answer and no particular insight to this problem, but Pycharm has various console panels where you usually find more in-depth error messages from lower level processes.

Comment: I have checked the logs and I do not see any more information about that error.

Comment: I have added the trace in case it helps

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue too.  I have the latest versions of all the related software as of the date of this post.

- Build #PY-222.4167.33, built on September 15, 2022
- Vagrant 2.3.0
- My pyramid app is on python 3.9.7

I am using the Intel Macbook Pro (i.e. not the M1s).

When I get the vagrant status error in the IDE, this is state of my macbook:

- vagrant is running
- I shut down computer for the night, unplug charger
- my macbook's battery is trash, so vagrant instance is halted
- I plug back in the next day, log back in with all apps still open (including Pycharm)
- I restart vagrant
- I get that status error when try to start app

And the solution?? Restart Pycharm.  That fixes it :shrugs: